# Autolayout ignoring constraints in Landscape

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view where an image view is on the upper left, a view containing a bunch of labels in on the upper right, a description is below, and a view containing a bunch of buttons is below.  I have constraints setup so the top items are the same height, width, same distance from the top and their respective sides and the description below them.  It seems to be ignoring the same height constraint in portrait, and gets totally wrong in landscape where the fields take over the whole screen.  Any ideas?  This just seems broken to me, I tried to simplify it as much as I could.

portrait:
ivCover frame: {{16, 12}, {250, 250}}
vwFields frame: {{211, 8}, {195, 250}}

landscape:
ivCover frame: {{16, 12}, {284, 248}}
vwFields frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't notice another developer made a bunch of different size classes.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I didn't notice another developer made a bunch of different size classes.  Check your size classes are set to wAny, hAny if you run into this.